# Swift - how automatically select cell when collectionView first loads up?

Tags: ios, swift, select, collectionview

I'm trying to figure out how to programmatically select a cell the moment the collectionView starts up. As in, the default load of the collectionView should have the first cell selected.

I'm using shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath for my selection function, so I want to call it for a specific cell index.

So far I have tried:

```
collectionView(self.collectionView!, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath: self.collectionView!.indexPathForCell(CVcellArray.first!)!)
```

In my viewDidLoad function for my custom CollectionView script.

It crashed when the collectionView loaded. Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `viewDidAppear` just call `selectItemAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Okay, so the problem I'm having with this is that I cannot access any Indexpath from within viewDidLoad. I create an array that keeps track of cells in my cellForItemAtIndexPath section later, but it seems like viewDidLoad is called earlier. Any pointers?

Comment: Can you create your own index path? For example

`let index = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)`

Comment: Hrm, nope. I just gave that a try. It crashed. It seems like the items are not yet generated by the time viewDidLoad is called? Is there another function I could call these in?

Comment: What about trying it in `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: perhaps late, but viewDidLoad is the first method that's called, collectionView is just starting , nothing set yet with the cells .. hence the crash~

Comment: Can you please share your code @user3488148 or Patrick Tescher