# Select Item in collectionView when the view appears

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2

I am trying to select my first cell in a collection view when the appears here is the code for it

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        categoryCollectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath
            , animated: false, scrollPosition: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition(rawValue: 0))
        self.collectionView(categoryCollectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPath)
    }
```

And I have in my collectionViewCell class an override to the isSelected variable to change the text color

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            if self.isSelected {
                self.categoryName.textColor = UIColor(red: 237/255, green: 28/255, blue: 36/255, alpha: 1.0)
            } else {
                self.categoryName.textColor = UIColor(red: 63/255, green: 62/255, blue: 62/255, alpha: 1.0)
            }
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work

I solve it by manipulating the isSelected property and it works fine

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView == self.categoryCollectionView {
            if let cell = categoryCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? CategoryCollectionViewCell {
                cell.configureCell(text: categories[indexPath.row].name)
                if indexPath.row == 0 {
                    cell.isSelected = true
                }
                return cell
            }
        } 
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if collectionView == self.categoryCollectionView {
            if indexPath != IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) {
                collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))?.isSelected = false
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: so you are trying to select a cell programmatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - how automatically select cell when collectionView first loads up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864679/swift-how-automatically-select-cell-when-collectionview-first-loads-up)

Comment: @Tobi yes and then when another cell is selected this should be unselected

Comment: @MohamedFarid ok

Answer (score 1):

```
            override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
              super.viewDidAppear(animated)

              let indexPathForFirstRow = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

              categoryCollectionView.selectItem(at: indexPathForFirstRow, animated:false, scrollPosition: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition(rawValue: 0))

              self.collectionView(paymentHeaderCollectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPathForFirstRow)     
    }
```

and inside DidSelect when user select another Cell, you can deselect cell like this

```
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let firstCell = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
    if indexPath != firstCell {
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false)
       }
}
```

for the isSelect Part you can Try this

```
override var selected: Bool {
    get {
        return super.selected
    }
    set {
        if newValue {
            super.selected = true
             //your Color
            println("selected")
        } else if newValue == false {
            super.selected = false
          //your Color
            println("deselected")
        }
    }
}
```

altho this could lead to problems the easier and best solution for this in my opinion is to create a flag isSelected inside the objects that you populate and check on them and switch between them inside the didSelect

Comment: It should work but I have an error cause of .left 
'attempt to scroll to invalid index path: <NSIndexPath: 0x6000026d0280> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'

Comment: try it as .top  instead of .left

Comment: please note me if this worked for you , @MohamedFarid happy coding

Comment: same error I almost tried all available options the only one that works is `UICollectionView.ScrollPosition(rawValue: 0)`

Comment: well use it then, i hope i was helpful ill edit the answer for you accept it if you may thanks,

Comment: I am sorry but it is still does't work it compiles but the first cell color is not yet selected

Comment: the problem with the color ? not selecting ?

Comment: you need the cell to be colored ?

Comment: because isSelected, you are not setting it any value yet,   and what is isSelected the first cell ? or any cell if you make that clear i can help

Comment: Yes exactly may be it is selected but the color doesn't change so it means that the isSelected property didn't change yet

Comment: ok i edited try the new selected override, and add  a break point

Comment: I did it with out using even view did appear will edit my question for you to see it thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below and it will work for me if cell in 0 index.

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = ScenarioCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ReuseScenarioCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ScenarioCollectionViewCell

if (indexPath.row == 0){
    collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally)
    cell.layer.borderColor=UIColor.gray.cgColor        
}else{
    cell.layer.borderColor=UIColor.white.cgColor
}
    return cell
}
```

i hope it will work for you.